# How to do a query search in Dart?

Tags: arrays, dart, search

I need to do a search by query in a List

like this:

```
final List<String> products = ['apple', 'ball', 'mouse', 'smartphone'];

List<String> search(){
    //All the code
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<String> products = ['apple', 'ball', 'mouse', 'smartphone']; 


List<String> search(String inputText){
    //All the code

    var result = products.where((product) =>
      product.toLowerCase().contains(inputText.toLowerCase());

    return result;
    
}
```